# fish: Unknown command '__fish_pwd'

Tags: macos, shell, homebrew, fish

So I was trying to install `fish shell` in OSX Yosemite using brew and I ended up with this. Any help is greatly appreciated as I am stuck with this:

```
mona@ > history
fish: Unknown command '__fish_pwd'
fish: echo $_ " "; __fish_pwd
                   ^
in command substitution
    called on standard input

fish: Unknown command 'less'
- (line 1): begin; less 
                   ^
from sourcing file -
    called on line 60 of file /usr/local/Cellar/fish/2.2.0/share/fish/functions/eval.fish

in function 'eval'
    called on line 42 of file /usr/local/Cellar/fish/2.2.0/share/fish/functions/history.fish

in function 'history'
    called on standard input

fish: Unknown command 'sed'
/usr/local/Cellar/fish/2.2.0/share/fish/functions/prompt_pwd.fish (line 2):     echo $PWD | sed -e "s|^$realhome|~|" $args_pre -e 's-\([^/.]\)[^/]*/-\1/-g' $args_post
                                                                                            ^
in function 'prompt_pwd'
    called on line 6 of file /usr/local/Cellar/fish/2.2.0/share/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish

in command substitution
    called on line 4 of file /usr/local/Cellar/fish/2.2.0/share/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish

in function 'fish_prompt'
    called on standard input

in command substitution
    called on standard input

fish: Unknown command '__fish_pwd'
fish: echo $_ " "; __fish_pwd
                   ^
in command substitution
    called on standard input

mona@ >
```

Comment: If fish can't find `less` or `sed`, then you may have a borked `$PATH`. What does `echo $PATH` show?

Comment: can you post your fish config? ( .config/fish/config.fish )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the problem by deleting the config.fish file by browsing to finder UI and Go to the folder utility.

Answer (score 1):

You might have a look at this tutorial for [Installing Fish Shell on Mac OS X](https://hackercodex.com/guide/install-fish-shell-mac-ubuntu/), which was written specifically for Yosemite and El Capitan.