# Fish Unknown command: __fish_pwd

Tags: macos, homebrew, fish, apple-m1

When running any commands in fish I am getting the following error:

```
fish: Unknown command: __fish_pwd
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/fish/3.2.2/share/fish/functions/fish_title.fish (line 1): 
__fish_pwd
^
in command substitution
        called on line 6 of file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fish/3.2.2/share/fish/functions/fish_title.fish
in function 'fish_title' with arguments 'echo\ \$PATH'
in command substitution
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/fish/3.2.2/share/fish/functions/fish_title.fish (line 6): Unknown error while evaluating command substitution
        echo (set -q argv[1] && echo $argv[1] || status current-command) (__fish_pwd)
                                                                         ^
```

Not really sure how to resolve this. I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling fish.

Other solutions i've seen ([fish: Unknown command '__fish_pwd'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911494/fish-unknown-command-fish-pwd)) suggest deleting `config.fish`, but there's nothing in mine except my PATH.

My `$PATH` looks like this:

```
/sbin /opt/homebrew/bin /opt/homebrew/sbin /Users/[username]/usr/bin /bin /Users/[username]/bin /Users/[username]/sbin /sbin
```

Comment: Does the file `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/fish/3.2.2/share/fish/functions/__fish_pwd.fish` exist? (It should). What does `echo $fish_function_path` show?

Comment: @ridiculous_fish yes that file does exist. Here's what `echo $fish_function_path` returns: https://gist.github.com/tbhockey/a5f6e82070ffdf0d11475ffc8fe3ed48

Comment: What does `uname` say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like your $PATH is broken because it doesn't contain `uname`.

It's probably in /usr/bin or /usr/sbin ("/usr" is *not /Users*), which you're missing.

(fish uses `uname` here to determine whether you're on Cygwin, in which case it would alter the $PWD it prints in the title. That's of course supremely cheesy and the error message is "unknown error" which should be improved. Regardless, your $PATH is not complete so you should fix it)

> but there's nothing in mine except my PATH.

Please try removing that and restarting all your fish sessions. Most likely that'll fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you! I think that was it! I was setting many of those paths as `$HOME/usr/bin/..` where they should have just been `/usr/bin...`. Things seem to be working normally now